# Why do we use Application Context in Constructors in Android?

Tags: android, android-room

While using Room Database i found that classes like Repository and ViewModel used Application  Context as arguments in their Constructors.

I Just want to know the reason,why this is done?
And is it a Compulsion to use the application context?

```
public WordViewModel (Application application) {
   super(application);
   mRepository = new WordRepository(application);
   mAllWords = mRepository.getAllWords();
}

 WordRepository(Application application) {
   WordRoomDatabase db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
   mWordDao = db.wordDao();
   mAllWords = mWordDao.getAllWords();
```

}

Curious to Know the reason behind the stuff

Comment: You're interested in the inner workings of a library. That's good. That said, have you already looked up the documentation in the source code before asking this question? (EDIT: you can alt+click a function in Android Studio to navigate to the source)

Comment: if the question is good why is it downcast???

Answer (score 1):

1. Why can't we use a Activity Context?

> Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.
>
> ViewModel objects are designed to outlive specific instantiations of views or LifecycleOwners. This design also means you can write tests to cover a ViewModel more easily as it doesn't know about view and Lifecycle objects.

2. Why can we use a Application Context?

> If the ViewModel needs the Application context, for example to find a system service, it can extend the AndroidViewModel class and have a constructor that receives the Application in the constructor, since Application class extends Context.

See [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Answer (score 1):

let me give you a lazy answer  to this question. Application context lifecycle is tied to the lifecycle of the application whereas activity context is tied to the lifecycle of that activity. Make sure to use the right context to prevent memory leaks . Hope this helps